# Implementing Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) in Class

Tags: javascript

I'd like to re-factor `Cache` class so it does not violate Single Responsibility Principle (SRP).

However, I'm having a tough time figuring out how I can re-factor unnecessary steps in `Cache` class into `memoize` function. Ideally I would have two methods in the `Cache` class `get` and `set`

```
function isObject(arg) {
  const typeOfObj = typeof arg;
  return (typeOfObj === 'object' || typeOfObj === 'function') && arg !== null;
}

class Cache {
  constructor() {
    this.map = new Map();
    this.weakmap = new WeakMap();
  }

  // create or retrieve a nested Cache instance based on an arguments object
  get(args) {
    let cache = this;

    for (const key of args) {
      const map = cache[isObject(key) ? 'weakmap' : 'map'];
      cache = map.get(key) || map.set(key, new Cache()).get(key);
    }

    return cache;
  }
}

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = new Cache();

  return (...args) => {
    // get (or create) a cache item

    const item = cache.get(args);
    if (Reflect.has(item, 'value')) {
      return item.value;
    }
    return (item.value = fn(args));
  };
}

let counter = 1;
function foo() {
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}

const id1 = Symbol('id');
const id2 = Symbol('id');
const obj1 = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = { a: 1 };

const memoizedFoo = memoize(foo);
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj1)); // 4
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj1)); // 4
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj2)); // 5
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj2)); // 5
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 6
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 6
console.log(memoizedFoo(4)); // 7
console.log(memoizedFoo(4)); // 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to have 3 methods on a `NestedCache` class:

- getNestedMap, to iterate through the maps, given an array of keys
- getMap, to get the value at a key in a particular Map
- setKeyIfNeeded, to set the value at a key for a Map, if it doesn't exist yet

You can use `reduce` to iterate through the array of keys instead of continually reassigning the `cache` variable, to be a bit more functional, if you want.

```js
function isObject(arg) {
  const typeOfObj = typeof arg;
  return (typeOfObj === 'object' || typeOfObj === 'function') && arg !== null;
}

class NestedCache {
  constructor() {
    this.map = new Map();
    this.weakmap = new WeakMap();
  }

  // retrieve a nested Cache instance based on an array of keys
  getNestedMap(keys) {
    return keys.reduce((cache, key) => cache.getMap(key), this);
  }
  // return a Cache's value at a key
  getMap(key) {
    const map = this[isObject(key) ? 'weakmap' : 'map'];
    this.setKeyIfNeeded(map, key);
    return map.get(key);
  }
  // create a Cache's key, if needed
  setKeyIfNeeded(map, key) {
    if (!map.has(key)) {
      map.set(key, new NestedCache());
    }
  }
}

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = new NestedCache();

  return (...args) => {
    // get (or create) a cache item
    const item = cache.getNestedMap(args);
    if (Reflect.has(item, 'value')) {
      return item.value;
    }
    return (item.value = fn(args));
  };
}

let counter = 1;
function foo() {
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}

const id1 = Symbol('id');
const id2 = Symbol('id');
const obj1 = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = { a: 1 };

const memoizedFoo = memoize(foo);
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj1)); // 4
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj1)); // 4
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj2)); // 5
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj2)); // 5
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 6
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 6
console.log(memoizedFoo(4)); // 7
console.log(memoizedFoo(4)); // 7
```

Comment: I am trying to get `getNestedMap` out of the `Class` if it is possible

Comment: Technically, it'd be pretty trivial to move the `getNestedMap` out https://jsfiddle.net/mnhcp8s3/, but it (and the `getMap` and `setKeyIfNeeded`) are all more related to the `NestedCache` than anything else, I think.

Comment: I see your point. so, it makes sense just to have it in the Class

Comment: I think so - without the methods related to nested operations, the Cache class wouldn't really be more than a plain object.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I really appreciate it!